# Explorer restarting periodically on Windows 10

Tags: drivers, windows-explorer, windows-10

I just did a rebuild of my system, and to finish it off I did a clean install of Windows 10 x64.

Things are going smoothly, except every so often explorer seems to restart, accompanied by the sound of a device being plugged in and unplugged.
I can force the problem to happen by searching for devices in the settings app, as shown [here](http://gfycat.com/IdolizedPastelCommabutterfly).

How can I begin to troubleshoot this issue? Is there a Windows log file that might explain it?

I've done memory tests and stability tests -- both pass.

Edit: File Explorer windows do not close when the problem occurs, suggesting that explorer isn't actually crashing but rather something else is responsible for the issues.

Comment: capture a crash dump ad share the compressed dump: http://pastebin.com/WACz5GBU

Comment: @magicandre1981 I added the key and forced the problem several times, but no dump was created. My registry config is per http://i.imgur.com/4j2E6Sk.png I assume that this means that explorer is not actually crashing, and that it is some other issue causing the graphical glitch. Open file explorer windows do not close when the issue occurs, providing further evidence that explorer is not actually crashing.

Comment: yeah, in this case Explorer is not crashing. look with this tool http://www.eventghost.org/ for eject/insert events of devices.

Comment: @magicandre1981 This is what is getting added/removed: 

System.DeviceAttached [u'\\\\?\\DISPLAY#OVR0003#5&8d010a1&0&UID4353#{e6f07b5f-ee97-4a90-b076-33f57bf4eaa7}']

System.DeviceRemoved [u'\\\\?\\DISPLAY#OVR0003#5&8d010a1&0&UID4353#{e6f07b5f-ee97-4a90-b076-33f57bf4eaa7}']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the OVR string returned by EventGhost at magicandre1981's suggestion I theorized that it might be the Oculus Virtual Reality headset I had plugged in causing the issue. Sure enough, unplugging the headset resolved the problem. Windows 10 isn't yet supported in the Oculus runtime, so I expect that I will need to leave it unplugged until that support is added.

Comment: nice to hear that you were able to figure it out :)

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks for the help. Eventghost is a tool I will keep in my toolkit in the future.